# Why not change permissions for Airflow RBAC default users?

Tags: permissions, airflow

In the Airflow documentation under RBAC Security, it states

> Airflow ships with a set of roles by default: Admin, User, Op, Viewer, and Public. Only Admin users could configure/alter the permissions for other roles. But it is not recommended that Admin users alter these default roles in any way by removing or adding permissions to these roles.

Let's say I want a User to be able to change their own password. Only Admins can do this by default but I could allow it by just altering their permissions on the relevant views. Is it instead preferred I create a new role with that permission? Or is this a bad idea for some other reason?